# Laravel API Call to a member function createToken() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-api

AuthController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Requests\Api\RegisterRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function signUp(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        $user = User::create($data);
        Auth::attempt(['username'=>$data['username'], 'password'=>$data['password']]);
        $token = auth()->user()->createToken($data['username']);

        return response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'username' => $user->username,
            'token' => $token->plainTextToken,
        ], 201);
    }
```

Router

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController;

Route::post('/signup', [AuthController::class, 'signUp'])->name('auth.signup');
```

When I send a request in postman to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/signup I get an error Call to a member function createToken() on null in file D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\demoA\app \Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController.php on line 18

I tried to install Sanctum, but because I'm new, I don't know if I did it right

Answer (score 0):

Login attempt doesnt work. Because You should save password with HASH.

You should encrypt password before store the user in DB.

```
$data = $request->validated();
$data['password'] = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
$user = User::create($data);
```

---

But will be better to use `Auth::login($user)` method instead of `Auth::attempt()`.

Comment: I tried using this code but the error remains. The user is created in the database, but the token cannot be created

Comment: The same error?

Comment: Yes, error remaining

Comment: Also, when I send a request to postman, I get the home.blade.php template, although this is not specified anywhere in my methods

Comment: You get home.blade because already signed in. Can you check sanctum configuration?

Answer (score 0):

tries to use the same object created at that moment:

```
$user = User::create($data);

Auth::login($user);

return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'username' => $user->username,
            'token' => $user->createToken($request->username)->plainTextToken,
        ], 201);
```